# Time complexity of finding whether graph has a unique topological order

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, graph-theory

I have this algorithm for finding whether directed graph has a unique topological order

1. Initialise list L
2. Find vertex V which is a sink in this graph (sink = vertex from which are not going any ordered edges)
3. From graph remove all edges going into V and then vertex V
4. Add V into L
5. If there are vertices left in graph go to step number 2

At the end I have topological order of vertices in L. If I can choose from more than one vertex in step number 2 then this topological order is not unique. If I got stuck in any of those steps before graph is empty that means that this graph has no topological order at all.

I assumed that time complexity of this algorithm would be O(n), where n is number of vertices in graph but apparently this is not right.

Comment: I Think That A Unique Topological Order Exists If The Graphs (DAG) Is Like 1->2->3->...->n (Or A Permutation). I'm Not 100% Sure.

Comment: @LeandroCastilloValdés 
Maybe I did not understand your comment right but I am not trying to determine when topological order exists but what is time complexity of this algorithm. This algorithm is working and it is right.

Comment: Your Solution Is Not O(N). If The Graph Is Like N->(N-1)->...->1 And You Find Sink In Order (1, 2, ...) Then You Get O(N^2).

Comment: When you say "Apparently that's not right" were you given a different answer? If so what was it? I don't know what the answer is. To me, it seems your algorithm is `O(nm)`. You may be able to improve that by using clever data structures, but I'm yet to be convinced it's possible in `O(m + n)`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp I don't know right answer, only that this one is not. Now I also see that time complexity is `O(mn)`

Comment: @DavidEisenstat is correct. You can do it in `O(n+m)`, using your algorithm. I'll set it out in an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `m` be the number of edges, and `n` the number of vertices. A naive implementation of your algorithm is `O(nm)`. If you implement step 2 by iterating over the set of edges that would be an `O(m)` iteration within a loop that could be executed `n` times.

However, you can do it in time complexity `O(n+m)` as follows. I will assume that a vertex is stored as an integer and an edge is stored as a pair of integers for tail and head.

**Step A**

In addition to `L`, initialise the following

(a) An array `A` with one slot for each vertex. The array should store for each vertex `i` a list of all vertices pointing towards `i`.

(b) A stack `S` of vertices that are sinks (so can be removed).

(c) An array `B`, again with one slot for each vertex. This array should store for each vertex `i` the *number* of edges that point *away* from `i`. When this number drops to zero, the corresponding vertex must be a sink so can be added to `S`.

**Step B**

Start by iterating over the set of edges. For each edge `E: i -> j` increment `B[i]` by one and add `E` to the list `A[j]`. This iteration is `O(m)`.

**Step C**

Iterate over the array `B` and if `B[i] == 0`, add `i` to the stack `S`. This is `O(m)`.

**Step D**

Step D is a while loop

```
while (S is not empty) {
```

Remove the first sink `i` from `S` and add it to `L`. Because you have a list `A[i]` you know all the edges that point to `i`. For each one of these edges `E: j-> i` remove the edge by subtracting `1` from `B[j]`. If the value of `B[j]` has dropped to zero, add `j` to `S`

```
}.
```

At the end of Step D all sinks will have been removed. Step D is `O(n+m)` simply because each vertex is removed at most once, and each edge is read at most once.

Answer (score 0):

The data structures aren't specified, but with good choices, the running time would be O(m + n), where m is the number of edges and n is the number of vertices. For a dense graph, it may be that m >> n, so O(n) time is not enough to read the entire graph. Conversely, if the graph is disconnected, then it may be that n >> m, so both terms inside the big O are necessary.

Comment: What do you mean specifically with good choices?

If I understand it right then most time complex part is to determine whether vertex V is a sink. Would using DFS or BFS work for this? (then I would have time complexity O(m+n))

Comment: @Superian007 It won't, because you're doing it over and over.

Comment: Can you clarify this? Surely step 2 alone is `O(m)` because you have to check every edge to know if a vertex is a sink? But since this occurs within a loop I can't see how it can be better than `O(nm)`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp Keep the vertices bucket-sorted by degree.

Comment: How do you sort in linear time?

Comment: Could you please try to describe why it has time complexity O(m + n) on some example? I don't think I understand it right. If I remove at every iteration one vertex (assuming graph has unique topological order) then why it would not work?

Comment: @pbabcdefp The degrees are integers between 0 and n-1.

Comment: @pbabcdefp now I get why there must be `m`. I did not realise that I need to check every edge in the V.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (I could be) but doesn't the best known algorithm to sort `n` numbers in the range `0,1,2, ...,n-1`  have time complexity `O(n log n)`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks for that. I thought I might be wrong. but I'm still not convinced you can do the whole thing in `O(n + m)`. Every time you remove an edge the vertices would have to be resorted, so the sorting algorithm would take place within the body of a loop.

Comment: @pbabcdefp You just have to rebucket it. Another possibility is to just track degrees without sorting and remember how many vertices of in-degree 0 there are.

Comment: No idea what the downvote is for, as this is clearly correct. @DavidEisenstat, there should always be exactly one vertex of in-degree/out-degree `0` I think, the transitive closure always has to be a linear order unless I'm mistaken.